# Quasar 2.2.2, Vue 3 and Firebase: how to access GlobalProperties from router

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar

I'm implementing for the first time Firebase in my Quasar App (with Vue 3). I've created the boot file firebase.js and this is its content:

```
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";

// "async" is optional;
// more info on params: https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli/boot-files
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'XXX',
  authDomain: 'XXX',
  projectId: 'XXX',
  storageBucket: 'XXX',
  messagingSenderId: 'XXX',
  appId: 'XXX',
  measurementId: 'XXX'
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analyticsApp = getAnalytics(firebaseApp);

 firebaseApp.getCurrentUser = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const unsubscribe = firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        unsubscribe();
        resolve(user);
      }, reject);
    })
  };

export default boot(({ app }) => {
  app.config.globalProperties.$firebase = firebaseApp;
  app.config.globalProperties.$analytics = analyticsApp;
})
```

The initialization seems to work fine. Now I must add a function to my index.ts located into router dirctory which allow me to redirect to a specific page when the user is not authenticated.

```
 Router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
    const auth = to.meta.requiresAuth
    if (auth && !await $firebase.getCurrentUser()) {
      next('/');
    } else {
      next();
    }
  })
```

$firebase must reference the globalproperties item. But whatever I've changed I'm unable to access the property.

Can you help me?

Roberto

Answer (score 2):

Looking carefully into Quasar documentation I've made all the changes in the firebase.js file which now is like this.

```
/* eslint-disable */
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'XXX',
  authDomain: 'XXX',
  projectId: 'XXX',
  storageBucket: 'XXX',
  messagingSenderId: 'XXX',
  appId: 'XXX',
  measurementId: 'XXX'
};

const firebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(firebase);

 firebase.getCurrentUser = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        unsubscribe();
        resolve(user);
      }, reject);
    })
  };

export default boot(({ app, router, store }) => {
  app.config.globalProperties.$firebase = firebase;
  app.config.globalProperties.$analytics = analytics;

  router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
    const auth = to.meta.requiresAuth
    if (auth && !await firebase.getCurrentUser()) {
      next('/');
    } else {
      next();
    }
  })
})

export { firebase, analytics };
```

Essentially I've changed the export boot clause adding router and store in it and I've added router.beforeEach in the clause.

I've made a debug session and the function is called everytime a route change occurs.

Roberto